# MLO generation in u-boot cross-compilation

Tags: bootloader, u-boot

Where I can find the piece of code responsible to generate MLO file?

In u-boot source code if I want to find the place belongs to creation of MLO file where I can findout the place.

Answer (score 0):

The code related to making **MLO** is found in *tools/omapimage.c* and *tools/omapimage.h*.